# How fix sweatalert2 font-family problem in vuejs/vuetify project?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuejs/vuetify project and I'm using sweatalert2. It works fine, but with one problem, the text on the alerts have a wrong font-family.
[image]
I tried to fix it this way:

```js
import swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js'
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';
```

but it didn't work. I think maybe the problem is related to vuetify, because in another laravel/vue project I used vue-bootstrap, sweatalert2 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the text font-family by overriding the rule

```css
.swal-overlay {
   font-family: "yourfont";
}
```